# Simplification of the Normal Kernel

Tags: normal-distribution, arithmetic

The kernel of the normal distribution is typically written as :
$ p(\theta | \mu, \sigma^2) \propto \exp\Big(- \dfrac{(\theta-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big)$
where the normalizing constant is: $C = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}$.

I have some lecture notes where this is simplified to:

$ p(\theta | \mu, \sigma^2) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp\Big(- \dfrac{(\theta-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big)$

$ p(\theta | \mu, \sigma^2) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp\Big(- \dfrac{\theta^2-2\mu\theta + \mu^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big)$

$ p(\theta | \mu, \sigma^2) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp\Big( \dfrac{-\mu^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big) \exp\Big(- \dfrac{\theta^2 - 2\mu \theta}{2\sigma^2} \Big)$

So the kernel simply becomes

$ p(\theta | \mu, \sigma^2) \propto \exp\Big(- \dfrac{\theta^2 - 2\mu \theta}{2\sigma^2} \Big)$ 
with normalizing constant: $C= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp \Big( \dfrac{-\mu^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big)$

I'm confused about the part where the exp is splitten in to two. How is: 
$ \exp \Big( \dfrac{ab}{c} \Big) = \exp \Big( \dfrac{a}{c} \Big) \exp \Big( \dfrac{b}{c} \Big) $ ??

Comment: It's not.  In your block of three equations, look at line 2 carefully and compare it to your question.  Write out what $a$ is and what $b$ is.  Is $ab/c$ really what's in line 2?

Comment: The relevant property is $\exp(a + b) = \exp(a)\exp(b)$

Comment: Ah.. I think I get it. So exp((a+b)/c)) = exp(a/c)*exp(b/c)